# Lanching Intent App Crashes

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-intent

I am new to android development trying to launch a new activity. When the button onclick is hit on the register button the new activity launches and I am able to complete everything I need to. However when I try to launch the Menu activity the app crashes. I looked and the activity was in the android manifest file.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

android manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Register"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_register"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Menu"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_menu"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"/>
</application>
```

MainActivity.java

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

EditText usernameEt, passwordEt;
//String JSON_STRING;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();

        }
    });

    usernameEt = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etUserName);
    passwordEt = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etPassword);
}

public void OnLogin(View view) {
    String username = usernameEt.getText().toString();
    String password = passwordEt.getText().toString();
    String type = "login";
    BackgroundWorker backgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker(this);

    backgroundWorker.execute(type, username, password);

}

public void OpenReg(View view){
    startActivity(new Intent(this, Register.class));
}


public void mainMenu(View view){
    startActivity(new Intent(this, Menu.class));

}
```

Here is the code for the two buttons

```
 <Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Register"
    android:id="@+id/btn_reg"
    android:onClick="OpenReg"
    android:layout_below="@+id/btnLogin"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/btnLogin"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/btnLogin"
    android:layout_marginTop="103dp" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="main menu"
    android:id="@+id/btn_menu"
    android:onClick="mainMenu"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/btn_reg"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/etPassword"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/etPassword" />
```

Here is the stack track

```
 03-28 12:25:19.533: D/TaskPersister(1232): removeObsoleteFile: deleting file=167_task_thumbnail.png
03-28 12:25:34.101: I/ActivityManager(1232): START u0 {cmp=com.example.dancastillo.mysqldemo/android.view.Menu} from uid 10059 on display 0
03-28 12:25:34.102: D/AndroidRuntime(11715): Shutting down VM
03-28 12:25:34.102: E/AndroidRuntime(11715): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-28 12:25:34.102: E/AndroidRuntime(11715): Process: com.example.dancastillo.mysqldemo, PID: 11715
03-28 12:25:34.102: E/AndroidRuntime(11715): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
03-28 12:25:34.102: E/AndroidRuntime(11715):    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:275)
03-28 12:25:34.102: E/AndroidRuntime(11715):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780)
03-28 12:25:34.102: E/AndroidRuntime(11715):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866)
03-28 12:25:34.102: E/AndroidRuntime(11715):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
03-28 12:25:34.102: E/AndroidRuntime(11715):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
03-28 12:25:34.102: E/AndroidRuntime(11715):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
03-28 12:25:34.102: E/AndroidRuntime(11715):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
03-28 12:25:34.102: E/AndroidRuntime(11715):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
03-28 12:25:34.102: E/AndroidRuntime(11715):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
03-28 12:25:34.102: E/AndroidRuntime(11715):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
03-28 12:25:34.102: E/AndroidRuntime(11715):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
03-28 12:25:34.102: E/AndroidRuntime(11715): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
03-28 12:25:34.102: E/AndroidRuntime(11715):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
03-28 12:25:34.102: E/AndroidRuntime(11715):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
03-28 12:25:34.102: E/AndroidRuntime(11715):    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:270)
03-28 12:25:34.102: E/AndroidRuntime(11715):    ... 10 more
03-28 12:25:34.102: E/AndroidRuntime(11715): Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.dancastillo.mysqldemo/android.view.Menu}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
03-28 12:25:34.102: E/AndroidRuntime(11715):    at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1777)
03-28 12:25:34.102: E/AndroidRuntime(11715):    at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1501)
03-28 12:25:34.102: E/AndroidRuntime(11715):    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3745)
03-28 12:25:34.102: E/AndroidRuntime(11715):    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3706)
03-28 12:25:34.102: E/AndroidRuntime(11715):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:784)
03-28 12:25:34.102: E/AndroidRuntime(11715):    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4016)
03-28 12:25:34.102: E/AndroidRuntime(11715):    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3984)
03-28 12:25:34.102: E/AndroidRuntime(11715):    at com.example.dancastillo.mysqldemo.MainActivity.mainMenu(MainActivity.java:69)
03-28 12:25:34.102: E/AndroidRuntime(11715):    ... 13 more
03-28 12:25:34.103: W/ActivityManager(1232):   Force finishing activity 1 com.example.dancastillo.mysqldemo/.MainActivity
03-28 12:25:34.107: W/AudioTrack(1232): AUDIO_OUTPUT_FLAG_FAST denied by client
03-28 12:25:34.114: D/(1232): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xa331c750, tid 1706
03-28 12:25:34.131: E/EGL_emulation(931): tid 931: eglCreateSyncKHR(1288): error 0x3004 (EGL_BAD_ATTRIBUTE)
```

Comment: Use LogCat to examine the Java stack trace associated with your crash: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this

Comment: LogCat says activityNotFoundException check android manifest. However I have the android manifest file there and the activity is present.

Comment: post full stack trace

Comment: Is all the three java files under same folder

Comment: I edited the question for the stack trace and yes MainActivity, Register, and Menu are all under the same folder

Comment: Try to use MainActivity.this instead of this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just simply change the name of activity Menu to `MenuActivity`; because [Menu](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Menu.html) class is used in android sdk.